# ECMA-335 I.12.6.8 Memory Clarifications - Zeroed Object and Padding Byte Guarantees?

Tags: c#, standards, ecma

The ECMA-335 specifies the following for the memory model,

## I.12.6.8

### Other memory model issues

> All memory allocated for static variables (other than those assigned RVAs within a PE file, see Partition II) and objects shall be zeroed before they are made visible to any user code.

This line is phrased slightly ambiguously. If all objects should be zeroed, does this include any platform-specific padding bytes added to the object?

e.g.

```
struct Foo 
{
    public byte mA;
    // 3 bytes padding here
    public int mB;
}

void Bar()
{
    // initobj is emitted here, will this zero the padding bytes?
    var foo = new Foo();
    // initobj is omitted here, the object will not be given its default value. 
    // Is the object then guaranteed to at least be zeroed? 
    // Will the padding be zero as well?
    Foo otherFoo;
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "static object" or "non-static object" - could you clarify *exactly* what you mean by those phrases in your question?

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the question to be a bit clearer.

Comment: i'm guessing so. it would be silly to skip zeroing any padding.

Comment: I've seen lots of code trying to combat noise/non-determinism from padding bytes. So I am curious if this is something that *should be* a non-issue based on the standard's specifications. Of course implementers can provide a non-standard implementation which doesn't zero padding bytes, but the wording in the standard doesn't seem to specify padding bytes should be zeroed explicitly. As such it's unclear to me if any implementation that doesn't zero padding is non-standard or not.

Comment: I would personally interpret it as requiring zero padding, as it's part of "memory allocated for an object". But I agree it could be worded more precisely.